# Baffling IndexOutOfBoundsArray Exception

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Can any one of you fine folks tell me what would possibly be causing this C# method to throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception? It would be much appreciated.

```
    public bool PopulateStudents(string path)   //decided to return bool if successful reading file.
    {
        theStudentList = new List<Student>(); //create instance..
        string text = null;
        FileInfo source = new FileInfo(@path);
        bool success = true;
        try
        {
            StreamReader r = source.OpenText();
            text = r.ReadLine();
            string[] splitText = new string[23];
            Student currentStudent = new Student();
            while (text != null)
            {
                splitText = text.Split(',');
                currentStudent = new Student(splitText[0], splitText[1], splitText[2]);
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i += 2)
                {
                    currentStudent.EnterGrade(int.Parse(splitText[i + 3]), int.Parse(splitText[i + 4]));
                }
                currentStudent.CalGrade();
                theStudentList.Add(currentStudent);
                text = r.ReadLine();
            }
            r.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            success = false;
            Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
        }

        return success;

    }
```

Sample input file:

```
0199911,Bill,Gates,27,30,56,60,0,30,83,100,57,60,0,30,59,60,0,30,59,60,88,100
0199912,Steve,Jobs,30,30,55,60,25,30,70,100,55,60,25,30,50,60,0,30,58,60,80,100
0199913,Marc,Andresen,30,30,55,60,25,30,70,100,55,60,25,30,50,60,0,30,58,60,80,100
0199914,Larry,Ellisen,30,30,55,60,25,30,70,100,55,60,25,30,50,60,0,30,58,60,80,100
```

EDIT: All of your answers are great and much appreciated, but as it turns out I just had some empty blank space at the end of my text file. I would like to point out that the responses you provided would fix this problem if I were to keep the blank space at the end. :)

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file?

Comment: Please show which line is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you read a line with less than 23 commas. Most likely this is an empty line in the end.

You should do

```
if (splitText.Length<24)
{
  WarnLogOrDoSomethingElse(text);
  continue;
}
```

immediately after

```
splitText = text.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you assign the return of `text.Split(',')` to `splitText` you are replacing your array of length 23 with an array that has a length equal to the number of tokens that result from splitting the `text`.  You need to check how many items are now in your array before accessing specific items and the loop should probably use `splitText.Length` as an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you say:

```
splitText = text.Split(', ');
```

You presume further down your loop that your always going to get 23 elements I suspect this might not always be the case.